# "Asked <place time since here>" is wrong

Tags: bug

Looking at the image below you'll notice that it's been almost 5 months since this was written but the "Asked x amount of months ago" is states it's been 3 months. Which is obviously wrong. The tooltip shows the correct date though (Jan 6th).

[image: Screenshot with arrows showing the issue]

I'm guessing this is a bug.

Comment: There's a (related?) issue somewhere about the rounding used in different places being _inconsistent_, but this seems just entirely _wrong_.  4 months and any number of days shouldn't round down to three.

Comment: @RyanM I just saw this and thought: "it's time for my rep on Meta to grow"

Comment: Hmmm, hate to break it, but it was only 4 months, and the fourth month is due to be over in 3 days (hence "3 months ago"). That said, SE's conversion of dates to relative datetime is a bit weird. I'd assume mathematical rounding too.

Comment: This is a fairly typical round down to the lower value (i.e. as mentioned, it's currently not been 4 months, yet).

Comment: Possibly similar to "[12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67371802/)" (asked 3 May '21) vs "[1 year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352418/)" (asked 2 May '21) (assuming today is already 3 May '22)

Comment: Ooops.  I can't do math.  Oleg and Makyen are right.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Sigh, this is very confusing, I also assumed it was 5 months ago for some reason. Well. I'll leave the question open here anyways, since it's not a duplicate

Comment: @KitangaNday no worries there - just wanted to point out that technically, the date's correct, however, there is a bigger underlying issue - IIRC, there are at least 3 different helpers across the SE codebase that do rounding *differently*.

Comment: I "*hate*" all those Relative Times/Dates anyway all over the Site, some get updated IRT, some not, it's always confusing when checking some open Tab "later" (hours or days) again, Dates less than 6(?)-12(?) months ago don't even mention the year, I would prefer a "clear" Timestamp (in International Format) and do the Calculation myself... // The only place with Timestamps is the 'Timeline' + `toggle format` (which can't even be remembered), this should be a Global Setting in our Preferences...

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine and chivracq Seeing both your comments I think it's safe to say that this needs to change: having multiple time parsers. Since, time is quite important when I'm picking a question to answer or back when I'd go as far as checking when the user was last online to see if a question is worth answering. Nothing hurts more than doing all the research for an answer to find that the user hasn't even seen it. Even a "Thank you" is good enough for flip's sake. Anywho, looks like this was worth posting since it shows that time being fixed is still something needed.